# How to Thread this application

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, object-detection, marvin-framework

I am using Marvin framework and Java CV (OpenCV),

Objective : - To detect Green region in video and make a rectangle over that area.

Solution : - Using Marvin Framework , i have been able to detect green region in static image

Problem :- Getting problem doing the same in video , as per frame has to be scanned from x,y coordinates and rectangle has to be made , it is not even showing the detection , performance  issues also.

1) Class [MarvinTest](http://pastebin.com/RHsLZ4rW)  : which get frame from video and send to SkinDetection class to detect green colored area.

2)Class [SkinColordetection](http://pastebin.com/v28NNQSe) : which detect the green region and draw rectangle through it.

Video is made by using this [static image](http://s22.postimg.org/rsnee7pbl/hand_pic2.jpg) moving using movie maker.
Need help executing it , the video is running but green colored region is not being highlighted by rectangle.

Comment: It's simply too much code for people to help you. Check [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got problem in Thread where i was iterating through x and y coordinate of every frame
so , now in marvin framework we have sample program , where it takes care of this issue.

It has been resolved